# How to change my code in order to solve byte overflow problem

Tags: c#, overflow

I am new to C#.

Why do I get a different result when using these two methods:

Method I

```
  byte x = 255;
  x = x + 1;
```

Method II

```
  byte x = 255;
  x += 1;
```

Method I results in an error an cannot be successfully compiled.

S0266  C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

If I add a cast and write

```
byte x = (byte)255;
x = x + 1;
```

The cast is then redundant.

If I write

```
byte x = 255;
x = x + (byte)1;
```

The cast is again redundant.

What can I do in order to get 0 as a result using method I?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the specification, section 7.8.4 has to do with the addition operators. Here, it outlines the four predefined integer addition operators as the following:

> int operator +(int x, int y);
>
> uint operator +(uint x, uint y);
>
> long operator +(long x, long y);
>
> ulong operator +(ulong x, ulong y);

Since `System.Byte` has an implicit conversion to integer, and the second operand is an integer, the actual operator being used is `int operator +(int x, int y)`, which returns an integer.

You can get your code to compile by casting the result of the addition to a `byte`, like so:

```
x = (byte)(x + 1);
```

Of course, if you do this with your example values in a `checked` context, expect an `OverflowException`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Converting int to byte requires an explicit cast, so you would have to write

```
byte x = 255;
x = (byte)(x + 1);
```

In general, implicit conversions (not requiring a cast) are reserved for lossless type conversions, and explicit conversions are for potentially lossy conversions which is the case with int to byte.

Comment: Thank you for your help!